How can I programmatically generate the table dependency hierarchy from selecting "View Dependencies" in SSMS?
In SSMS, I can right-click on a view, stored procedure or table in Object Explorer, select "View Dependencies", click on the circle next to "Objects on which [selected item] depends", and it produces a dependency hierarchy showing all the dependency objects.
I read this Microsoft article, which explained this process, and it also gave the following query for viewing dependencies.
SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(N'<insert view/stored procedure/table name here>')

However, thus far this has not returned output when I look for the dependencies of a table.
Is there a query that can reproduce the hierarchical output from selecting "View Dependencies" in the Object Explorer UI?  The hierarchical representation itself is not very important to us, and a flattened hierarchy represented in table format would more than suffice for our purposes.
Thank you for your help.

I think it uses some voodoo to extract deps from actual code as well as the above table or the older sysdep-views. Do you have a simple recreation script for missing deps?

There's some more info here as well https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1294/how-do-you-identify-object-dependencies-in-sql-server/

Use SQL Server Profiler to view batch of queries/script executed before calling dependencies window.
